# Check the class of an aspx label using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

Inside my Content page I have a repeater control, which contains multiple controls along with a lable. The Id of lable is "`LEmptyComments`". My requirement is to check if the class name of the label is empty or not. The If block never executes what am I doing wrong?

```
function chkCmnts() {

        var val = 1;
        $("label[id*='LEmptyComments']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).className != "") {
                val = 0;
                return val;
            }
        });
        return val;

    }
```

This is how the lable look like in the HTML page :

```
 <span id="MainContent_DlReviewImages_LEmptyComments_13" class="error">...... </span>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the selector (`$("label[id*='LEmptyComments']")`) is returning results? If so, have you tried viewing the source of the your ASPX page? I would recommend posting the generated HTML code from your ASPX page if just viewing the source doesn't help you find the problem on your own.

Comment: @KileyNaro, seems the selector is not returning the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` is not a valid jQuery function or property, however you're calling it on a jQuery object. Additionally, you're looping over `label`s and not `span`s:

```
function chkCmnts() {
    var val = 1;
    $("span[id*='LEmptyComments']").each(function () {
        if (this.className) { // "" is falsey
            val = 0;
            return val;
        }
    });
    return val;
}
```

You could actually replace this entire thing with one jQuery statement and a conditional operator on the `length` of that statement:

```
function chkCmnts() {
    return $("span[id*='LEmptyComments'][class!='']").length > 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LLKbP/

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats works like charm. Wondering in addition to 'LEmptyComments' if I have to do the same for another lable 'LEmptyCategory' is it possible to add it in the same span[id*= ]

Comment: No problem. I think what you're asking is how to combine multiple selectors, which you can do just by using a comma (`,`): `$("selector1, selector2")....`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var class = $("#<%=LEmptyComments.ClientID%>").attr("class");
```

**EDIT**

Revised to work with the ASP.NET Label control

Comment: Sorry, just realized that you said it was an ASP.NET label. Revised answer should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

"label" isn't an HTML element, it's an ASP.NET control type.

Rather than trying to match the asp.net generated ID for a control inside a repeater, why don't you just assign a known class to use as a marker in advance for each label. This way you can easily get the set of controls you're trying to test.

Once you have that just check for whatever you want.

```
$('.repeater-label').each(function() {
    if (this.className != 'repeater-label') {
        /// any elements with classes other than just repeater-label
    }
});
```

"repeater-label" is a class added to everything you want to look at inside the repeater, presumably, it will have some other class too for the elements you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use :  `$("#LEmptyComments")`..........

and you don't have to use each since there is only one ( should be ).

Comment: as i mentioned the label is inside the repeator control which is insdie a content page, meaning there are multiple lables. this is how the lable looks like in the HTML  <span id="MainContent_DlReviewImages_LEmptyComments_13" class="error">

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem but I would ask what you are trying to achieve as there might be a better solution.

```
function chkCmnts() {

        var val = 1;
        $("#LEmptyComments").each(function () {
            if ($(this).className != "") {
                val = 0;
                return val;
            }
        });
        return val;

    }
```